# telling mercurial to ignore a file when merging and updating

Tags: mercurial

I want mercurial to ignore my own local copy of log/development.log (I am on RoR).

I used "hg forget filename" to forget the file, and then committed that change.

It seems to be successful now.. but every time I merge with other changesets now, I see

```
remote changed log/development.log which local deleted
use (c)hanged version or leave (d)eleted?
```

what am I doing wrong? how can I make this msg go away? I just want my local copy to be separate from the copy in the repository.

Thank you...

Comment: additionally, I added this file to .hgignore if that makes a difference

Comment: have you put .hgignore under source control so that it is passed along to the copies, also?

Comment: hmm but I dont want the other users to be affected by my .hgignore though...

Comment: is there are way to do this? or must it be in source control?

Comment: btw i added .hgignore to my own .hgignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deleted the file in your line, and you merge it with the one that still has this file, this message is to be expected. The only way to get rid of it is to remove this file from the repos/branches you're merging with (or get their owners to remove it, if you don't control them).

And then never commit a temporary log file into the repository ever again.